# Rewrite sum on tuples

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Let $J_n:=\{1,\dots,n\}$ and let $f:\mathcal{P}(J_n)\to[0,\infty]$ be a map on the power set $\mathcal{P}(J_n)\equiv 2^{J_n}$. For any $0\leq m\leq n$, define $F_m := \sum_{S\subseteq J_n:|S|=m}f(S)$ and $L_m := \sum_{j_1,\dots,j_m\in J_n}f(\{j_1,\dots,j_m\})$. The goal is to rewrite $F_m$ as a linear combination of $L_m$.

Examples: Clearly $F_0 = L_0$, $F_1=L_1$.

Now the problem starts for higher $m$, since already for $m=2$ we are over-counting. Firstly because $\{j_1,j_2\}=\{j_2,j_1\}$ and secondly because $\{j_1,j_1\}=\{j_1\}$. To deal with this I thought that one could first remove the diagonal term and then divide by two: $F_2 = \frac{1}{2}(L_2-L_1)$.

Assuming this is correct, I would like to derive such a formula of $F_m$ for arbitrary $m$. What I could come up with is $F_m=\frac{1}{m!}(L_m-\frac{m(m-1)}{2}L_{m-1})$.

My question is: is this correct? If not, what is the correct formula to express $F_m$ in terms of $L_{m'}$?

Comment: Can you give more terms in the expression $L_m - m F_{m - 1} - \ldots - F_1$? Because I don't see what pattern is implied.

Comment: @P.Senden, I edited the expression to update my "guess".

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the summation for $F_m$ includes ${n \choose m}$ terms, while the summation for $L_m$ includes $n^m$ terms (many of which are repeats), right?  If so, for the constant function $f() = 1$, we have $F_m = {n \choose m}$ and $L_m = n^m$.  I _think_ this means your proposed recurrence is wrong.  I've not much idea how to find the correct recurrence though...  After all it seems pretty difficult to write ${n \choose m}$ in terms of $n^m, n^{m-1}, \dots, n$.

Comment: @antkam Thank you, I understand. Somehow this is puzzling since if the sums were replaced by integrals then we know very easily that we can ignore the diagonals (which are of measure zero) and then just $F_m = \frac{1}{m!}L_m$. Surely there must be a discrete version of that?